# Can I ask questions about how software is supposed to be used?

Tags: discussion, scope

I just asked a question about what the intended workflow is for doing something in Ubuntu, but it was rather poorly received thus far:

[What is the intended way of creating desktop launchers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/617168/why-is-creating-desktop-launchers-so-difficult-what-is-the-intended-workflow)

Is this not an appropriate question for this forum? Usually when I come across a feature or workflow that I'm used to doing and find it to be unusually difficult in a new environment, I try to find solutions to the same problem *in a different way*. This was my intention here, but it seems to have been received as a rant. That wasn't my intention, but I don't how to clarify this without stripping away the context of the question.

Now I'm wondering whether this is a question I should be asking here at all. I've had a read of the "[What topics can I ask about here](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic)" page and it doesn't really seem to cover this kind of question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Asking this:

```
Why is creating desktop launchers so difficult?
```

is a matter of opinion. I myself do not believe it is difficult and many others do not believe it too.

By the way: you list the page from the help but there is also the [don't ask page](https://askubuntu.com/help/dont-ask) that has:

> Some subjective questions are allowed, but “subjective” does not mean “anything goes”. All subjective questions are expected to be constructive. What does that mean? Constructive subjective questions:
>
> - inspire answers that explain “why” and “how”
> - tend to have long, not short, answers
> - have a constructive, fair, and impartial tone
> - invite sharing experiences over opinions
> - insist that opinion be backed up with facts and references
> - are more than just mindless social fun